# Unable to set cookie in express + passport with nodejs

Tags: express, passport-local

Here i'm trying to set cookie when user select **remember**  checkbox when user logins, but even the console.log("hello"); is not working.

```
// process the login form
        app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
            }), function(req, res) {
            console.log("hello");

            if (req.body.remember) {

              req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 3;
            } else {
              req.session.cookie.expires = false;
            }
          res.redirect('/');
    });
```

but i tried directly setting with express.session it works fine like below

```
app.use(express.session(
    {   secret: 'sessionmaxageset',  
        cookie: { maxAge : 3600000 } 
    } 
)); // session secret
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code is mainly based on http://runnable.com/UTlPPF-f2W1TAAET/how-to-use-cookies-in-express-for-node-js. I am using Express 4.2.0 so the body-parser and cookie-parser middleware has to be installed using npm. [New middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware) is now superseeding cookie-parser called cookies.js and keygrip.js.

```
SERVER.JS

    var express = require('express');
    var app = module.exports = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var http = require('http');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var colours = require('colors');

    var port = process.env.PORT || 4000;        //set the port

    // parses request cookies, populating
    // req.cookies and req.signedCookies
    // when the secret is passed, used 
    // for signing the cookies.
    app.use(cookieParser('secret-string'));

    // parses json, x-www-form-urlencoded, and multipart/form-data
    app.use( bodyParser() );
    app.use( logger() );

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {

     if (req.cookies.remember) {
        res.send('Remembered :). Click to <a href="/forget">forget!.');
      } 
      else {
       res.send('<form method="post">Check to <label>'+ '<input type="checkbox" 
       name="remember"/> remember me </label> /' + '<input type="submit"  
       value="Submit"/>.   
       ');
      }
    });

    app.get('/forget', function(req, res) {
      res.clearCookie('remember');
      res.redirect('back');
    });

    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
      var minute = 60 * 1000;
      if (req.body.remember) 
        res.cookie('remember', 1, { maxAge: minute });

      res.redirect('back');
    });

    var server = app.listen(port, function() {
      console.log('Listening on port %d' .green , server.address().port)
    });
```