# Node express and passport remember-me authentication

Tags: node.js, cookies, express, passport.js, remember-me

I am looking into implementing remember-me authentication on my node app. I've managed to make all sessions have a cookie by adding a parameter to my cookie in my express session.

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: constants.session_secret,
  store: new MemcachedStore({
    hosts: [config.memcached.host + ':' + config.memcached.port]
  }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 300000, // <-- This line
    httpOnly: true
  }
}));
```

However, I want to allow the user to choose by adding a remember me checkbox on the login page.

I would greatly appreciate any hints or articles in order to better understand How to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812512/unable-to-set-cookie-in-express-passport-with-nodejs/23829536#23829536

Answer (score 0):

You can update session any time you want. app.use is just middleware and you can declare one more before this one to perform any logic.

```
// any route function(req, res) or middleware

var hour = 3600000
req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour)
req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour

req.session.save(function(err) {
  // session saved
})
```

see session project page for more info https://github.com/expressjs/session